# How can I set an <ArrayList> as a constructor in main()?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have done a lot of research for the answer and have implemented and have implemented it in my code.

[declaring ArrayList in java Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736092/declaring-arraylist-in-java-constructor/22736164)

I am getting the error

`required: String`

`found: String,String,String,String,String,String,String`

`reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

I can not see why?

Basically I am trying to make a dice called easy which is a String

It has 6 sides which are represented as String.

The fill up method is just to populates the ArrayList with the dice object.

I have a constructor in my class Dice which I am using to set the name of the Dice and the sides, this is where the error occurs.

I have tried different syntax I have found online, setting the length to 5 and 6 and nothing has worked.

```
import java.util.*;
class diceGame{
    // calling main method
    public static void main (String[] args){

        //Calling the method which asks user for how many players are 
                playing
        //and also the players names.
        Player [] arrayPlayers = createPlayersArray();

        //Fills the cup with all 13 dices at the start of each turn
        ArrayList<Dice> arrayDice = fillCup();


}




    public static  ArrayList<Dice> fillCup(){

        //Player array to hold all the players
        ArrayList<Dice> diceArray = new ArrayList<Dice>(13);

        Dice easy = new Dice("Green:","Brain","Brain","Brain","Foot Print","Foot Print","Shotgun");


        int numberOfEasyDice = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++ ) {

            if (numberOfEasyDice < 13) {
                diceArray.add(easy);
                numberOfEasyDice++;
            }
        };

        return diceArray;
    }

}







//////////////Dice class
import java.util.*;
class Dice{
    public List<String> side; 
    public String name;


    //This is the constructor I am using
    public Dice (String n){
        name = n;
        side =new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //Setter and Getter name
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public static int roll(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int rolledNumber = r.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.println(rolledNumber);
        return rolledNumber;
    }


}
```

The final result will be that every time a dice is used it can be taken out of the ArrayList.

Comment: Your `Dice` constructor is defined as `public Dice (String n){` meaning when you construct a `Dice` object it takes in a single `String` parameter. However, when you call the constructor, you are doing `new Dice("Green:","Brain","Brain","Brain","Foot Print","Foot Print","Shotgun")`, passing in 7 `String` parameters as input. You need to either pass in a single `String` as input or define another constructor that can take in 7 `String` inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error here is that you are invoking the Dice constructor with multiple Strings, even though the constructor only accepts one String.

```
// Errornous line
Dice easy = new Dice("Green:","Brain","Brain","Brain","Foot Print","Foot Print","Shotgun");

// compare the invocation to the constructor in Dice...
public Dice (String n) { ... }
```

Thus, you have to replace the way you initialize your Dice instance, like so:

```
// Initialize it this way instead
Dice easy = new Dice("Green");
```

But, it seems to me that the way you have built the Dice class, is not the way you actually want it to work.

Let me try to clarify this:

- You stated that you want to build a dice
- You want each side of the dice to have a distinct string.
- BUT: You only accept one String in your Dice constructor (`public Dice(String n)`)

Therefore, what you have to do is to rework your constructor in such a way, that you can actually pass in each side of the Dice. Don't forget to store it in the List as well.

This seems to be a homework related task, so I don't feel comfortable to be more specific than that.

Good luck in your studies!

Comment: Haha I am actually this is a Assignment I got last year and struggled with so I was trying it out again before the start of year 2. Thanks for the push in the right direction and being helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

```
class Dice {
    public List<String> side;
    public String[] names;

    public Dice(String... names) {
        this.names = names;
        side = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // The rest of the class

}
```

Then you can create a `Dice` object with

```
Dice easy = new Dice("Green:","Brain","Brain","Brain","Foot Print","Foot Print","Shotgun");
```